# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Visual Studio Push Notifications

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, azure-notificationhub, visual-studio-cordova

We are in the process of starting development on an iOS, Android and Windows Phone application when I came accross this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx

I know it's only in preview but I wanted to put together a test bed to see if we could achieve what we want with this and then have a single project to maintain but I cannot find any information about how we go about getting push notifications to the app.

How using this framework do we get the channelUri or device token?  After much googling I am still unable to find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub) to send push notification using Azure Notification Hub. It supports iOS, Android, WP8 and Windows 8. Follow the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx#Custom to add a plugin from Git repository.

You might also find blog post [Push Notifications to PhoneGap Apps using Notification Hubs Integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/17/push-notifications-to-phonegap-apps-using-notification-hubs-integration.aspx) helpful in case you want to use [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

Answer (score 0):

That framework is an extension of the cordova framework.
http://cordova.apache.org/

In order to get push notification functionality, you would need to install a cordova plugin.  I have used this one successfully.  I'm not sure how Visual studios handles plugins but you should be able to get it installed.
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Then you need to use the phonegap plugin to register the device and save off the device token to a database somewhere.

Then you can use a service like Azure Mobile Services to send out push notifications for all your registered devices.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-push/

Azure has a few different ways to send out and register push notifications either via notification hubs or through their push api.

Answer (score 0):

If you using CPT, for include the cordova pushplugin in a hybridapp proj you must have to manually edit your config.xml file and set the plugin path, because pushplugin is not in the standard plugin set of CPT.

```
<vs:feature>MYLOCALPLUGINPATH</vs:feature>
```

You can also use the github uri instead of local plugin path, but in that case visual studio still download it each time.